# Using multiple command in `subprocess.call`

Tags: python

I want to create a shell pipeline using `call`. For example, I want to run this code get the number of lines having 123:

The shell command would be:

```
grep "123" myfile | wc -l > sum.txt
```

But "123" is a variable so I want to use python:

```
A= ["123","1234","12345"]
for i in A:
   call(["grep", i,"| wc >> sum.txt"])
```

This code does not work!

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Do you get an error message, do you get unexpected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` only calls one executable. What you want is that executable to be a shell (e.g. `bash`), which parses the command line. `bash` is also responsible for handling pipes. You can do this using `shell=True` option, which is off by default.

When you give it an array like you do, then you are calling *that executable* with *those arguments*. A pipe is not an argument; and `grep` does not know how to pipe, nor how to invoke `wc`.

You can do

```
call(["grep '%s' myfile | wc >> sum.txt" % i, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the pipe character you would need `shell=True`,pass `i` each time using `str.format`:

```
 call('grep "{}" myfile | wc >> sum.txt'.format(i),shell=True)
```

You can also do it without `shell=True` and using python to open the file instead of shell redirection:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, check_call

p = Popen(["grep","myfile" i], stdout=PIPE)
with open('sum.txt', "a") as f:
    check_call(["wc"], stdin=p.stdout,stdout=f)
```

Also your `>`  and `>>` are not the same so what mode you open the file in will depend on which one you actually want to replicate

Comment: But I want to use `A` instead of 123!

Comment: @user1436187, then pass the variable each time using str.format as above